# How to see where the default database is configured for a particular username or login name?

Tags: sybase, sybase-ase, sybase-ase-15.7

Once I connect to a database server without specifying a particular database, e.g. with:

```
sqsh -Usomeuser -Ssomeserver
```

… I can do a:

```
select db_name();
```

… to see the default database for this user. But where is this information kept and / or how can I see the default databases configured for every user name or login name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the following code shows the default database on ASE:

```
SELECT sl.name
    , sl.dbname
FROM syslogins sl
ORDER BY sl.name;
```

Comment: I get `syslogins not found. Specify owner.objectname or use sp_help
to check whether the object exists ` Trying with `master.syslogins` produces the same result.

Comment: You don't have rights to see it, most likely.  It is in master, so you could specify it as `master.dbo.syslogins`

Comment: Another thing is that I noticed that the association is from login names (not user names) to databases. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

About default DB:

- default DB per login is held in the master DB system table `syslogins` column `dbname`
- this column is selectable by `public` group (everyone is in this group) i.e. select permission is granted to public
- alternative is to execute the system stored procedure `sp_displaylogin <loginname>` to display the default DB

You can check access permissions using `exec sp_helprotect syslogins` within the context of master DB.